# How to Save a PictureDrawable as a JPEG/PNG file in Android

Tags: java, android, image

I have PictureDrawable that I wish to save as an image (JPEG/PNG) but I can't seem to find any information how to go about this.

I tried this but it does not seem to work

```
PictureDrawable myDrawable = GetPictureDrawable(); 
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(200, 200, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
myDrawable.draw(new Canvas(bitmap));
bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100,  new FileOutputStream("/MyLocation/MyImage.jpg"));
```

What am I doing wrongly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
//Convert PictureDrawable to Bitmap
private static Bitmap pictureDrawable2Bitmap(PictureDrawable pictureDrawable){
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(pictureDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),pictureDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        canvas.drawPicture(pictureDrawable.getPicture());
        return bitmap;
    }
```